# How to select last data by field from table? In Laravel way

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Good day to you.

I want to select from my mySQL `keys` table **last** data by `serial` field:

```
           keys table:
serial | event_date_time | rest_data..
------ | --------------- | -----------
 sn005 | 2015-05-05      | data1
 sn001 | 2015-01-01      | data1
+sn005 | 2019-09-09      | data2
+sn001 | 2020-10-10      | data3
 sn001 | 2016-06-06      | data2  

          query result:
serial | event_date_time | rest_data..
------ | --------------- | -----------
 sn001 | 2020-10-10      | data3
 sn005 | 2019-09-09      | data2
```

I've got this query:

```
SELECT `k`.*
  FROM (
    SELECT `serial`, MAX(`event_date_time`) AS `event_date_time`
      FROM `keys`
      GROUP BY `serial`
  ) AS `d`
  JOIN `keys` AS `k`
    ON `k`.`serial` = `d`.`serial` AND `k`.`event_date_time` = `d`.`event_date_time`
```

And i have my concerns:
1. How to make this query work in laravel-eloquent way? Can't figure it out by reading [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects)
2. I feel query is complicated. Is there a way to simplify or optimize it?

ty for your time.

Comment: Please, explain one more time what your query should return...
The latest record (reverse ordering on `serial` column?) or.. what?

Comment: The latest records for all `serial`. You see, for me all other records is like history, i don't need it often. But i need actual list by this moment of time (one latest serial record).

Comment: //In controller after namespace :  `use Carbon\Carbon;`
//Query : 
DB::table('keys')
                ->groupBy('serial')
                ->having('event_date_time', '<', Carbon::today())
                ->get();

Comment: It sounds beautiful, but somehow it didn't work for me.

Comment: I think when it group by serial, query take fist record from table and does not look for event_date_time

Comment: I think the problem is in Date comparasion. What this query is returning now?
is that `event_date_time` column a string column or a date column?
Try to use `Carbon::now()->toDateString()` instead of `Carbon::now()`

Comment: I have 3 test records like: [id=>2, serial=>FFF, event_date_time=>2030],[id=>39, serial=>FFF, event_date_time=>2050],[id=>51, serial=>FFF, event_date_time=>2020]. This query return record with id=2, but i need id=39 because it is latest (2050). My monstrous query do it ))